# Why am I getting "unknown magic byte" error when deserializing this Avro schema with my app but not with kafka-avro-console-consumer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform

I am continuously sending data in Avro format to a topic called "SD_RTL". This data generation is possible through a Confluent datagen that conforms to a custom Avro schema.

When I use kafka-avro-console-consumer on this topic, I see my data correctly. Here's an example of one correctly received tuple:

`{"_id":1276215,"serialno":"0","timestamp":416481,"locationid":"Location_0","gpscoords":{"latitude":-2.9789479087622794,"longitude":-4.344459940322691},"data":{"tag1":0,"tag2":1}}`

The problem appears when I try to consume this data through a Java app. I get the error "unknown magic byte".

I am using the code inspired by the second snippet under the Serializer section in [confluent's website](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/serializer-formatter.html).

This is my code:

```java
//consumer properties
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group1");


        //string inputs and outputs
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer");
        props.put("schema.registry.url", "localhost:8081");

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

        //subscribe to topic
        String topic = "SD_RTL";
        final Consumer<String, SensorsPayload> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));

        try {
            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, SensorsPayload> records = consumer.poll(100);
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, SensorsPayload> record : records) {
                    System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s \n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
                }
            }
        } finally {
            consumer.close();
        }
```

My code and confluent's code are a bit different. For example, Confluent uses the line:

`final Consumer<String, GenericRecord> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);`

Whereas if I put the right part as `<String, String>` instead of `<String, SensorsPayload>`, IntelliJ complains about incompatible types. I'm not sure if it's related to my issue.

I've generated my SensorsPayload class automatically from an Avro schema through the avro-maven-plugin.

Why does my Consumer app generate an "unknown magic byte" error when kafka's avro console consumer does not?

Comment: Probably just means noone actually ever ran the code from Confluent, because it won't compile if they use generic types like that. IDE types error is valid.

Comment: It seems, your SensorsPayload schema doesn't conform to the schema used for serialization. Did you try to consume as `GenericRecord` instead of `SensorsPayload`?

Comment: @NishuTayal I replaced SensorsPayload with GenericRecord but I get the same error.